# Shows same length after deleting some items from list with remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have a list of 3 items in an unordered list as follows

```
<ul class = "list">
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Using .remove() I can remove the third as given

```
var listitems = $('.list li');
listitems.eq(2).remove();
```

then in dom i can see that the last item is removed. But if I

```
alert(listitems.length);
```

It shows that there are 3 items in the list inspite of only two items are showing in the window. Does javascript suppose tho behave like it? If yes please explain.

Comment: You have to access the listitems again using $('.list li'); and it shall show the correct length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting the `.list li` inside a variable at page load and its original value will be allocated to memory unless you update it. You will have to use `$('.list li').length` or update that variable:

```js
var listitems = $('.list li');
listitems.eq(2).remove();
console.log($('.list li').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class = "list">
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `listitems` variable isn't "live" - as with all jQuery objects it only remembers the state of the DOM as it was as the time you created it.

Comment: @Lalas Muathasim this will helpful $('.list li').eq(2).remove(); console.log($('.list li').length);

Answer (score 0):

@Ainitak is correct. Do this:

```
var listitems = $('.list li');
listitems.eq(2).remove();
listitems = $('.list li');
console.log(listitems.length);
```

Comment: Please add the explanation

Comment: The explanation is already in another answer and in the comment section. 
Still the thing is that jquery doesn't update the variable but just updates the DOM on ".remove()" call and hence one shall again access the DOM to get the correct length of DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
var listitems = $('.list li');
```

at this time listitems contains 3 as there is 3 items in dom. now when execute
listitems.eq(2).remove(); this line delete an element from dom not from  listitems.

before alert(listitems.length); you need to get li elements from dom . put this line before alert();

```
listitems = $('.list li');
```